# ListBox not populating

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am a beginner using VBA in Excel. I am trying to come up with a user form that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXLmO.png). I have all the coding in, but when I launch it from a command button in Excel, the ListBox does not populate. When I try to enter in numbers and click "submit" I get "Run-time error '424':Object required". When I click debug, it takes me to the line

```html
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = dotwListBox.Value
```

I am not sure what is going on. Any help would be appreciated!! Here is my code:

```html
Private Sub cancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub clear_Click()
Call UserForm1_Initialize

End Sub



Private Sub submit_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long
'Make Sheet3 active
Sheet3.Activate
'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = dotwListBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = t235tocbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = t235codbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = apiphbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = apiturbiditybTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = apitocbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = apicodbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = apibodbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = longbaydobTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = asudobTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = rasmlssbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = clarifierturbiditybTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = clarifierphbTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = clarifiernh3bTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = clarifierno3bTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = clarifierenterococcibTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = clarifierphosphorusbTextBox.Value




End Sub

Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
'Empty t235tocbTextBox
t235tocb.Value = ""
'Empty t235codTextBox
t235codb.Value = ""


'Fill dotwListBox
With dotwListBox
.AddItem "Monday"
.AddItem "Tuesday"
.AddItem "Wednesday"
.AddItem "Thursday"
.AddItem "Friday"
End With

'Empty apiphbTextBox
aphiphb.Value = "1"
'Empty apiturbiditybTextBox
apiturbidityb.Value = ""
'Empty apitocbTextBox
apitocb.Value = ""
'Empty apicodbTextBox
apicodb.Value = ""
'Empty apibodbTextBox
apibodb.Value = ""
'Empty longbaydobTextBox
longbaydob.Value = ""
'Empty asudobTextBox
asudob.Value = ""
'Empty rasmlssbTextBox
rasmlssb.Value = ""
'Empty clarifierturbiditybTextBox
clarifierturbidityb.Value = ""
'Empty clarifierphbTextBox
clarifierphb.Value = ""
'Empty clarifiernh3bTextBox
clarifiernh3b.Value = ""
'Empty clarifierno3bTextBox
clarifierno3b.Value = ""
'Empty clarifierenterococcibTextBox
clarifierenterococcib.Value = ""
'Empty clarifierphosphorusTextBox
clarifierphosphorusb.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `dotwListBox` the empty ListBox? If so, then there is no wonder why this is giving you an error. The `Sub UserForm_Initialize` should work if the ListBox has been named correctly. Maybe you want to check if the `(Name)` in the property window for the ListBox really is set to `dotwListBox`? Also, may I recommend that you start coding explicitly by adding a sheet and a workbook to `Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value`. For example like this `With Sheet3` and then `.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value`.

Comment: The name I was using was not the same as the name in the property window, so I fixed that. It still was not populating the ListBox so I ended up using the RowSource feature and pulled in the contents from a group of cells on an empty worksheet. And thank you for the tip about coding explicitly to a sheet! I am a beginner and anything that helps clarify my code is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons:

1. Your `ListBox` `MultiSelect` property is set to  1 (fmMultiSelectMulti) or 2 (fmMultiSelectExtented)

   In this case its `Value` property will be always Null
2. Your `ListBox` has no item selected

   even if its `MultiSelect` property is set to  0 (fmMultiSelectSingle) its `Value` property will return Null if no item is selected

   In this case set a check with its `ListIndex` property, like follows

`If dotwListBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = dotwListBox.Value`

Since -1 is the value returned by `ListIndex` property when no item is selected

Comment: @srs1011: did you get through it?

Comment: Yes in a round about sort of way. First, I fixed the name of the ListBox since I noticed I was referring to an incorrect name. Then I ended up having to populate the ListBox using the RowSource feature because I could not get it to populate otherwise when I hit the command button on my worksheet to launch the form. After that, everything worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: if the ListBox name weren't the right one, you'd meet an error right in the `UserForm1_Initialize` sub, which is run before the `submit_Click` one. While in your question you said that the error was met in this latter. Moreover even if you successfully populate your `ListBox` but then try `Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = dotwListBox.Value` without previously having the user (or the code) select a value, you'd still hit an error. So if you haven't set any `If dotwListBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then` check yet, I think you should do that. It'd be kind of you to let me know about these two issues. thank you

Comment: I have not added a check yet. So far everything that is selected/populated in my UserForm ends up populating in the worksheet with the code that I have running now. I guess I just am not sure what my original issue was.